# Pandas: join a row of data on specific index number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas
a=[['Date', 'letters', 'numbers', 'mixed'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1'], ['1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3']]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=a[0])

b= [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
df2 = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(b[1:],columns=b[0])
```

I want to join df2 on df so it looks like this:

```
       Date letters numbers mixed    a    b    c
0  1/2/2014       a       6    z1  
1  1/2/2014       a       3    z1    a    b    c
2  1/3/2014       c       1    x3
```

Looking through the docs, I got as close as `df=df.join(df2,how='outer')`

which gives you this:

```
       Date letters numbers mixed    a    b    c
0  1/2/2014       a       6    z1    a    b    c
1  1/2/2014       a       3    z1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1/3/2014       c       1    x3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I want something like `df=df.join(df2,how='outer', on_index = 1)`

Comment: There is no operation that will do what you want, you have to update your index value in order to place the df row where you want it as user Ffisegydd has shown in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already does do a join with a specific index, it just so happens to be that your index in `df2` is 0 and so when it joins it places the `'a', 'b', 'c'` in index 0.

```
import pandas

a=[['Date', 'letters', 'numbers', 'mixed'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1'], ['1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3']]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=a[0])

b= [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
df2 = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(b[1:],columns=b[0], index=[1])

df=df.join(df2,how='outer')

print(df)
#        Date letters numbers mixed    a    b    c
# 0  1/2/2014       a       6    z1  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 1  1/2/2014       a       3    z1    a    b    c
# 2  1/3/2014       c       1    x3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

In this code I have set the index of `df2` with the keyword argument `index = [1]`. If you cannot use this keyword argument then you can change the index (in this particular example) using `df2.index = [1]`, this should be done before joining the two DataFrames.

Comment: i see, so i have to re-index?

Comment: You have to make sure that the row that you want to join has the same index as where you want it to eventually be, yes. At the moment (without re-indexing) it's saying *"Oh well in `df2` I was in index 0 so I'll put myself in index 0 in `df`"*

Comment: how do I re-index to `1` after `df2` has been fed in already? I can't index it when I feed the `df` in.

Comment: @jason_cant_code for your toy example you can assign directly `df2.index = [1]`

Comment: @jason_cant_code Also see further examples: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#adding-an-index-to-an-existing-dataframe